# Dynamic field reference for nested structures

Tags: matlab, dynamic, struct

In our MATLAB code, we've been using [dynamic field references](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) a lot, and they're pretty fantastic. We have a lot of different data structures with different field sets, so it makes it a whole lot easier to access any one of them simply using the `struct.('field')` notation, without having to use an `eval` statement.

However, where we run into problems is that many of these structures have multiple levels, and we don't always know how deep into the structure we will need to go. Ideally we'd like to be able to access them without using an `eval` statement, perhaps something like

```
struct.('field.field2.field3')
```

Is there a way to dynamically access structures with unknown depth using the builtin functionality? Or will we have to create a custom function for accessing all of our structures?

Comment: But with `struct.('field.field2.field3')` you know the depth no? Or is it `struct.('unknown_amount_of_variables.desired_field')` ?

Comment: Or are you looking for `struct.('field').('field2').('field3')` ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri it's closest to `struct.('unknown_amount_of_variables.desired_field')`.

Comment: Do you need to read it, or write on it, or both? Can they repeat? can there be a `field3` in different locations in the structure?

Comment: Please explain how you obtain the dynamic field names.

Comment: Does knowing that `structB = structA.('fieldB');` doesn’t copy any data make this problem easier to solve?

Comment: *"[Dynamic field names] are pretty fantastic"* - this is pretty subjective, and generally not true from a performance, code readability, maintenance or robustness standpoint...

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I dont think its a duplicate, as OP mentioned they don't know the variables of the struct. Just that somewhere, there is one with that name.

Comment: @Wolfie can you elaborate on the performance implications?

Comment: @excaza I don't have a short benchmark for demonstration, but often in profiling code I've seen that the dot notation indexing can be a bottle neck - especially relative to matrix or cell array indexing for instance. Making data structures as flat as possible increases ease of access. As soon as you also need helper functions to find fields for you (as needed here), I can only imagine this gets many times more noticeable!  Don't get me wrong, they can often save a lot of work in workspace management and make things quicker to code, I'm just noting they're not the defacto best method

Comment: I reopenned the question because what OP asked is not what its in the dupe target.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I accepted the duplicate, because it is essentially the same as what I was intending to ask. I misunderstood your first comment for clarification. I do know the exact location of the desired field, but not until I am passed the string of fieldnames. What I don't know is whether that string will be two levels deep or five or twenty.

Comment: @DavidK but then you can not use the linked duplicate no? because you need to have all the fields to do so.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I am passed a string which might be `field1.desiredField` or `field1.field2.desiredField` or `field1.<more levels>.desiredField`. I will know exactly where the field is. I was trying to figure out if there was a builtin function that would allow me to access that field dynamically without using `eval` or having to parse and loop everything myself.

Comment: OK.... close as duplicate then.

Comment: @DavidK You may consider accepting this answer as valid, even if you ended up needing something else, for future readers that may have the problem you described

Answer (score 3):

This code works for the following assumptions and usage cases:

1. There is a field that you do not know where it is within some nested dynamic structure.
2. The name of this field is unique, i.e. there is no other field anywhere in the struct with the same name.

The following function works:

```
function [fieldplace]=findfield(s,field)

% is one of these?
fieldplace={};
if (isfield(s,field))
    fieldplace{end+1}=field;
    return;
end

if ~isstruct(s)
    fieldplace={};
    return;
end

% otherwise is nested somewhere, use recursivity.
fnames=fieldnames(s);
for ii=1:numel(fnames)
    fieldplace=findfield(s.(fnames{ii}),field);
    if ~isempty(fieldplace)
        fieldplace=[fnames{ii} fieldplace];
        return;
    end
end


end
```

Usage case:

```
s.a=1;
s.b.c=2;
s.b.d=3;
s.e.f.g=4;
s.h.i.j.k=5;
result=findfield(s,'k');
```

You can read the field as:

```
getfield(s,result{:})
```